# SSIS Failed foreign key constraint

Tags: sql-server, ssis, foreign-key, ssdt

I'm loading 2 csv files into 2 tables in SQL Server Data Tools using SSIS, and the 2nd one is connected to the 1st via a foreign key constraint. The problem is that a row of the 2nd table has a key that is missing from the 1st table, so the foreign key constraint fails and an error message is presented.

Is there a way to check the foreign key constraint before insertion and catch the error so that it doesn't interrupt the insertion of the rest of the rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IN SSIS, you can probably set up a lookup step with the foreign key data from table 1; rows that don't match could be routed into an error file, and the rest routed into the table.

Alternately, load the data into a staging table without the foreign key constraint, and run a script/stored procedure to validate the data in the staging table, including making sure the foreign keys are present.